# Qt two different design form class

Tags: c++, qt

I have two design form class , i want to insert into tabWidget (at pharmacymainwindow.ui ) the test2_tab_1 ( which is at test2.ui) ?

Any idea, how can i use ui object of a class at another ui ?
the ui of one design form class is private i have no idea how can i access it from another designer form class.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include just enough to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ui::test2 *ui` is a member-class responsible for filling a widget: `ui->setupUi(this)`, it is not a widget, so you should not use it to insert it in a tab, what you should do is create a widget and insert it:

```
void PharmacyMainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(0, new test2,"new tab");
}
```